# μ-law compression technique

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications, analog-to-digital, signal-synthesis

[image: μ-law compression formula]

In μ-law compression formula i have always seen that the value of Xmax and Ymax is always same but can they be different?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be different, depending what your maximum input value is.

Comment: But my maximum input value is Xmax.